# In Azure DevOps How to trigger releases using REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have build and release pipeline in Azure DevOps.
That pipeline contains a three different stages namely STAGING, QA and PROD.
So, after completion of deployment in QA slot I want to trigger PROD environment using REST API.
So, Is that possible to do the same?

Comment: Do you really need it to be triggered with the REST API? Have you looked through the out-of-the-box triggers? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#env-triggers

Comment: yeah, why dont you want to configure a stage trigger?

Comment: Yeah, as per requirements releases should be trigger by REST API.

Comment: @4c74356b41 Because QA task will perform on VM. So I need to trigger PROD release from that VM using REST API.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to do this in a single release pipeline. The release [create api](http://POST%20https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1) can only trigger the release pipeline to run, it cannot trigger a certain stage within the pipeline.
As the stages in the release pipeline only support **after release**,**after stage** and **manually**.

To achieve your requirements, You will have to separate your prod stage from this release(Release A), which means you will create a new release pipeline(Release B) with the a single stage prod environment.

Then you can add a powershell task at the end of QA stage in release pipeline A to call the API to trigger Release B to deploy to Prod environment. below script is for example:

```
$releaseUrl ="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/<organization>/<project>/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1"

$body = '{
  "definitionId": 4, # release definition id
  "description": "Creating prod release",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "_NunitProject", #artifacts alias
      "instanceReference": {
        "id": "1367", #build id related to the artifacts
        "name": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "isDraft": false,
  "reason": "none",
  "manualEnvironments": null,
  }'


$result4 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $releaseUrl -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" } -Method post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: Hi @akoliya01 Did you get a chance to try out below answer? Please let me know how did it go? We can discuss it to work out a better solution.

Comment: Hello @Levi Lu-MSFT - since this response is almost a year old, is this still the case can't I trigger a particular stage using REST API ? I have 3 pre-prod stages and two prod stages in same pipeline. I want to trigger a release either at the first pre-prod stage or the first prod stage. The Create Release API starts deployment only if the stage trigger type is "After Release"