# Azure DevOps release pipeline trigger when specific path contains changes

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a repository set up in Azure DevOps that contains some configuration for multiple applications. For every applications, a different release pipeline is set. Every single one of them has an automatic trigger set when a change inside the repository is pushed. I would want to only trigger the release pipeline for the application that the change is referring to. In the repo every app has its own folder. Is it possible to somehow specify a trigger filter for those release pipelines, so that a release pipeline for an application gets triggered only when changes happened in its folder inside the repo, and not when any change in the repo happened? Is this possible or does it have to be achieved via a custom script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that Release Pipeline doesn't support setting the Trigger Path filter for the time being.

For a workaround, we need to use custom script check the changed repo path before the Release Pipeline running.

We can setup a build pipeline to use git command to check the repo path first and then use extension task([Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline)) or Rest API(Refer to this ticket: [Trigger release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972567/in-azure-devops-how-to-trigger-releases-using-rest-api)) script to trigger the related Release Pipeline.

Refer to my sample to check changed path and trigger release pipeline:

```
trigger:
- main


steps:
- powershell: |
   $files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
   $temp=$files -split ' '
   $count=$temp.Length
   echo "Total changed $count files"
   For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
   {
     $name=$temp[$i]
     echo "this is $name file"
     if ($name -like "foldername/*")
       {
         Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ReleasePipelinename]ReleasePipelineName1"
       }
     if ($name -like "foldername2/*")
       {
         Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ReleasePipelinename]ReleasePipelineName2"
       }
   
   }
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

- task: TriggerPipeline@2
  displayName: 'Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline: Release'
  inputs:
    serviceConnection: serviceconnectionname
    project: projectname
    releaseDefinition: '$(ReleasePipelinename)'
```

The script above will use git diff command to get the changed files in the commit.

It will set the release pipeline name to the Pipeline variable according to the changed file name.

Then the Trigger pipeline task will trigger the release pipeline based on the variable value.

**Note:** If you consider triggering release pipeline in build pipeline task, you need to disable the triggers in Release Pipeline UI page.